# Distributing identical objects to different people.

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways in which we can distribute 12 identical oranges among 4 children such that every child gets at least one and no child gets more than 4 ?

Till now ,My attempts have focused on first finding out all such ways in each person gets at least one orange by ${ 13 \choose 3}$ and then trying to find out number of those ways in which at least one person gets more than 4 oranges. 
( Basically trying to apply to the inclusion- exclusion principle ) 
However, I have not been able to figure out the former ( i.e. number of ways in which each person gets more than 4 oranges ).

Is this approach the most suitable one , or should I look at something different ?

Comment: At this site, it is expected that you explain your thoughts on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: The number $\binom{13}{3}$ is too large.  Did you solve the problem in the positive integers or non-negative integers?

Comment: I tried solving the problem using only positive integers , as negative integers would connote that a child was getting negative oranges which seems absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of ways $12$ oranges can be distributed to four children if each child gets at least one orange is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 12 \tag{1}$$
in the positive integers.  A particular solution of equation 1 in the positive integers corresponds to the placement of three addition signs in the eleven spaces between successive ones in a row of $12$ ones. For instance,
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 3$, and $x_4 = 6$.  Hence, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{11}{3}$$

Since each child receives at most four oranges, we must exclude those solutions in which one or more of the variables exceeds $4$.  Since $3 \cdot 5 = 15 > 12$, at most two of the variables can exceed $4$ simultaneously.

Suppose $x_1 > 4$.  Let $y_1 = x_1 - 4$.  Then $y_1$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $y_1 + 4$ for $x_1$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 4 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 12\\
y_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 8 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers with $\binom{7}{3}$ solutions.  By symmetry, there are $\binom{7}{3}$ solutions in which one of the four variables exceeds $4$.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3}$$
solutions in which one variable exceeds $4$.

However, subtracting $\binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3}$ from $\binom{11}{3}$ removes those solutions in which two of the variables exceed $4$ twice.  Since we only want to remove such solutions once, we must add the number of solutions in which two of the variables exceed $4$.

Suppose $x_1$ and $x_2$ exceed $4$.  Let $y_1 = x_1 - 4$; let $y_2 = x_2 - 4$.  Then $y_1$ and $y_2$ are positive integers.  Substituting $y_1 + 4$ for $x_1$ and $y_2 + 4$ for $x_2$ in equation 1 yields 
\begin{align*}
y_1 + 4 + y_2 + 4 + x_3 + x_4 & = 12\\
y_1 + y_2 + x_3 + x_4 & = 4 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Equation 3 is an equation in the positive integers with one solution (each variable is equal to $1$).  By symmetry, there is one solution for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways in which two of the variables exceed $4$, so there are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{3}$$
solutions in which two of the variables exceed $4$.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of ways the twelve oranges can be distributed to four children so that each child receives at least one and at most four oranges is 
$$\binom{11}{3} - \binom{4}{1}\binom{7}{3} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{3}$$

Answer (score 2):

This can be represented as the number of integer solutions of the equation,
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=12$$
where $1\le x_i\le4$. Here, $x_i$ denotes the number of oranges given to the $i^{th}$ child.

This can be further represented as the coefficient of $x^{12}$ in the expansion of,
$$(x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^{4}$$

This can be evaluated using the value of the sum of a geometric progression and the binomial theorem.

In this, the powers of $x$ denote the allowed values of $x_i$. Since there are four children, we have raised the sum of the terms with $x$ raised to the allowed values to $4$. Now, in the expansion, $x^{12}$ occurs when some terms of $x$ in each of the four terms multiply together such that their powers add up to $12$. Each such combination contributes once to the coefficient of $x^{12}$, and thus, the coefficient gives the number of ways that this combination can occur, given the constraints.

Comment: Could please justify on representing as the coefficient of x^12 in the expansion ?

Also, I am confused on what if the number of children was 5 but the limit on oranges per student was 4 ?

Comment: @SuryakantShrivastava The only way you get $x^{12}$ in the expansion is when various powers of $x$ in the $4$ factors multiply to give $x^{12}$. For this to happen, the powers must add up to $12$. Each time this happens, the coefficient of $x^{12}$ increases by 1, and the total coefficient gives the number of ways this can be done. The number of factors denotes the number of variables, so for 5 children, the expression would be raised to 5. This is particularly useful when different variables have different constraints as each factor can be made to suit the constraints.